# Fast queryable collection of objects

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for a library that would accept a collection of objects and return an indexed data structure that would be optimised for fast querying.

This is probably better illustrated by an example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public sting Name {get;set;}
    public double Number {get;set;}
    public ... (Many more fields)
}     


var dataStore = Indexer.Parse(myClassCollection).Index(x => x.Name).Index(x => x.Number).Index( x => x.SomeOtherProperty);
var queryResult = dataStore.Where( x => x.Name == "ABC").Where(x => x.Number == 23).Where( x => x.SomeOtherProperty == dateTimeValue);
```

The idea is that the query on the `dataStore` will be very fast, of the order of `O(log n)`.

Using dictionaries of dictionaries starts getting complicated when you have more than 2 or 3 fields you want to index.

Is there a library that already exists that does something like this?

Comment: How about a database? SQLite or SQL Server Express comes to mind

Comment: As mentioned below, I would like to keep everything in memory. I know SQLite does have an in memory module, but it just feels heavyweight for what I am trying to do.

Comment: Pretty sure not in .NET from Microsoft.  .NET does not try and be a database (and I don't want it to be).  For collections the key is hashed and that is about it.  A DataTable can have multiple keys but DataTable is slow compared to .NET 4.0+ collections.  How many? LINQ to List is pretty fast.

Comment: Are you talking in-memory or persisted to disk?

Comment: This codeplex project seems to address this need: https://indexedlist.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

What about an [object oriented database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database).

[Sterling](http://sterling.codeplex.com/) is a recommended option. It supports LINQ to Object so don't worry about queries and we have used it for a couple of medium projects with good results (it's pretty fast).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I am looking for something very lightweight that keeps all information in memory. (i.e. I don't need to persist the data.). Sterling looks promising though. Will investigate further.

Comment: Had a look at Sterling and you have to inherit from a base class in order to store your objects in the database, which is a deal breaker. Something along the same lines is [NDatabase](http://ndatabase.codeplex.com/) which does not require a base class. It is not as nimble, expression wise, as what I originally wanted, however I have been testing it as a persistent OOD and am very happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at RaptorDB as well.  Several versions, including a fully embedded version, can be found on CodeProject [here](http://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=raptordb&x=0&y=0&sbo=kw).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Lucene.NET which can also run fully in memory (though I'm not sure that's what you'd want). It supports lightning fast retrieval of documents based on field criteria.

So that actually gives you a document database. If you take that one step further, you end up with something like RavenDB (commercial).

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering whether we could achieve this by creating a SortedDictionary for each of the indexed properties.

```
SortedDictionary<property, List<MyClass>>
```

Then parsing the Linq expression tree to find out which properties are being queried. We can retrieve the valid keys of the sortedDictionaries, and then loop through these keys to get a List for each sorted dictionary and then use Set operations such as Union() and Intersect() depending on whether the  expression tree has OR or AND directives. 
Then return the a List matching the search criteria.

If the query includes a property that is not indexed, execute the query with indexed properties first and then use normal Linq to finish it off.

The interesting bit then becomes parsing the expression tree.

Any thoughts on this approach?

Comment: This codeplex project seems to address this need: https://indexedlist.codeplex.com/